# Get the metadata from Spotify's current played song on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, metadata, playback, spotify

I want to play a simple program for Windows that gets data about the current played song from Spotify.
The standard approach seems to be to get the Window Title of Spotify and extract the Artist and the song name. Problem is that you can't get any information about the album or the playlist etc.

On Mac and Unix this seems to be possible.
(see http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Conky-Spotify-quot-Now-Playing-quot-scripts/td-p/26825 and [How to get currently playing track in Spotify Mac from Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236413/how-to-get-currently-playing-track-in-spotify-mac-from-cocoa)).

What I am looking for is a similiar way to get this metadata on Windows if there is any.
I am practically independent of programming language, it may be c, c#, c++, java, autoit...